# Is it possible in Provider just to send value data not all component content?

Tags: reactjs

Context API is not sending component content, just context value

```
import React, { useState t } from 'react'


const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {


  return (
<div>
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ foods: "foods"}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>

 ..... any many other data
</div>
  )
}

export default AppProvider
export { AppContext }
```

Here I want to get the value data from AppContext. The provider is not showing AppProvider other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using functional components, so you can use hooks

In the file you want to get only the value of the context, you import `AppContext` and inside the component and use `useContext`

e.g.

```
import { AppContext } from '...'
...

const ComponetThatWillOnlyGetTheValue  = () => {
    const { foods } = useContext(AppContext);
    return (
        <div>{foods}</div> // "foods"
    )
}
```

If you want to use a class component, you need to do a HOC and cosume the context ( in the same file that you created your `AppProvider`)

```
export function withAppContext(Component) {
    return function AppContextComponent(props) {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {context => <Component {...props} {...context} />}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

And wrap your component with the function `withAppContext`

e.g.

```
import { withAppContext } from '...'
...
class ComponetThatWillOnlyGetTheValue extends React.Component { ... }
export withAppContext(ComponetThatWillOnlyGetTheValue)
```

## Edit

Check the full working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/50425qk374)

Comment: tkx for answer but I get same error as : TypeError: Cannot read property 'foods' of undefined
```
const AppContext = React.createContext();
const AppProvider = () => {
  return (
<AppContext.Provider value={{ foods: "foods"}}></AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default AppProvider
export {AppContext}
----------- 
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './AppProvider';
const ComponetThatWillOnlyGetTheValue = () => {
  const {foods} = useContext(AppContext)
  return (
    <div>{foods}</div>
  )}
export default ComponetThatWillOnlyGetTheValue;
```

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi please check my edit with the full working example. The code you provided in the coments have some mistakes and that is why it gives the same error.

Comment: thank you Vencovsky, you did great effort. tkx and please check the sandbox example AppContext comment i have added.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9zx0l6oj4?fontsize=14